# Synaptic package manager not showing in applications menu

Tags: release-freya, applications

Using a fresh install of elementary OS Freya

I installed Synaptic and expected it to show up in the applications menu. It is not there. I am able to start Synaptic by typing the name in the search bar at the top of the icons. I can't find a way to display a full list of all my installed apps (including Synaptic).

Comment: I installed Synaptic too (and replace Ubuntu Software Center with Lubuntu Software Center) and it shows up as *Synaptic Package Manager* in Slingshot. By default it uses quite an ugly icon. One idea would be to check the [`.desktop` file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) in `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: @quassy you should probably repost that as an answer. If binary exists you're 100% correct and it's only a matter of the application shortcut being missing

Comment: Done. @Jeffrey Needle: Is Synaptic the only app missing from Slingshot for you?

Answer (score 2):

I installed Synaptic too and it shows up as *Synaptic Package Manager* in Slingshot (under *System Tools* if you use category view). By default it uses quite an ugly icon, this is how it looks like for me (with an [extended icon pack](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus) and unstable WingPanel):

[image: Synaptic in Slingshot]

One idea would be to check the [`synaptic.desktop`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries) file in `/usr/share/applications/`. It should look something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Synaptic Package Manager
GenericName=Package Manager
Comment=Install, remove and upgrade software packages
Exec=synaptic-pkexec
Icon=synaptic
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=PackageManager;GTK;System;Settings;
NotShowIn=KDE;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=synaptic
```

Quite important are the entries `NotShowIn` (should **not** contain `Pantheon`) and `OnlyShowIn` (**if** it's there, make sure it **does** contain `Pantheon`). There should not be an entry called `NoDisplay`. [(Learn more about recognized desktop entry keys.)](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)

If there is no such file first try to reinstall synaptic `sudo apt-get install --reinstall synaptic`.

If that does not work, use Scratch to create a new file called `synaptic.desktop` inside `~/.local/share/applications/` with the contents I have posted above.